# How to pass json as param in a function

Tags: jquery, json

I'm trying to learn Jquery. 
I have a problem: I have to send a json dynamically as param of a function. My code is this:

```
$('#grafo').append('<a class="list-group-item graph" href="#" id="' + nome.replace(/ /g,'') + '" onclick="printAnnotation(\'' + json + '\',\'' + index + '\')">' + name + '</a>');
```

I would like to get a json, but the results is a string.

How can I fix that ?

PS: sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Do not cast it into a string type. `"printAnnotation(json, index)">` would work

Comment: Can you show a little more of your code that shows where you have defined `json` and `index`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding an event handler from script instead ( https://api.jquery.com/click/ ):

```
$('#grafo').click(
    function()
    {
        printAnnotation( json, index );
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're embedding your JSON inline in the DOM like that you're stuck with a string. This isn't a big deal though, because you can turn the string into a JSON object inside your function. Like so:

```
function printAnnotation(jsonString, index) {
  var json = JSON.parse(jsonString);
  // do stuff
}
```

Comment: He doesn't work :( I get :" Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token" o on the parse

Comment: your json string is also invalid then. Can you post the generated value that's in the DOM?

Comment: I generated it thanks to query sparql. I return a jsonp.

Comment: But when I try to print the json before the line above, print correctly !

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the string to JSON using `JSON.parse()` method or the jQuery equivalent [`$.parseJSON`](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB0QFjAAahUKEwjyoprz14PIAhVDShQKHaacADY&url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.jquery.com%2Fjquery.parsejson%2F&usg=AFQjCNGgBEiZzAMHqQ-wyR2v45gFivhN6A&sig2=6ZsbTPbhgYIb8sgc-ZxNwQ).

**Note:** When passing a Javascript object embedded in HTML (for instance in a function call), *stringify* the object in accordance to JSON format using [`JSON.stringify()`](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB0QFjAAahUKEwjjl8qo2YPIAhWEPxQKHaHGByU&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen-US%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FJavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FJSON%2Fstringify&usg=AFQjCNHsam3cInn4frfXmEzE5ZghVWRvqw&sig2=fqehUFyadWcmpJQvkw97Jw) method:

```
$('#grafo').append('<a class="list-group-item graph" href="#" id="' + nome.replace(/ /g,'') + '" onclick="printAnnotation(\'' + JSON.stringify(json) + '\',\'' + index + '\')">' + name + '</a>');
```